# Java command line args cross output

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I need to write a program that reads an command prompt argument (int n) that then outputs a cross made of Xs depending on the number, so an arg of 3 would output this

http://i.imgur.com/a441t0X.png

X would increase or decrease depending on the number in the arg

im not really sure how to go about this

Comment: I suggest you start by writing down the steps you need to solve the problem. This description should be in English (or whatever natural language you are comfortable with).

Comment: So, what have you tried? How do you think you should approach the problem?

Comment: i don't know how to approach the problem,, the instructions are extremely vague

Comment: What is it about the requirements/instructions that you find vague?

Comment: If you were to break the problem into a number of smaller problems (say two for example), what would they be?

Comment: well i guess i would read the args, then output the cross based on the number

but i dont know how to output the cross

Comment: See my answer below for the algorithm (approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an algorithm (not actual code) for printing the cross (assuming the argument passed in is referred to as **count**):

```
LOOP(count times)
    LOOP(count times)
        PRINT space_character
    ENDLOOP
    PRINT "X"
    PRINT newline
ENDLOOP

LOOP(count times)
    PRINT "X"
ENDLOOP

PRINT " "

LOOP(count times)
    PRINT "X"
ENDLOOP

PRINT newline

LOOP(count times)
    LOOP(count times)
        PRINT space_character
    ENDLOOP
    PRINT "X"
    PRINT newline
ENDLOOP
```

Comment: thats good, the big issue im having is how vague the requirements are

Comment: What is it about the requirements that you find vague? To me they seem clear: read a number from command line argument and produce the appropriate output (as shown in your image) sized according to the number.

Comment: welll one of the other requirements is error checking, which i have already sorted, i just dont know how to print out a big bloody (variable) Cross made of Xs

Comment: @user3101679 That's what my answer is trying to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this, the best way to start though is to break it up into loops.

So there would be a loop to create the first vertical section. Then one to produce the second horizontal and finally one to produces the last vertical section

Comment: the big problem with this is that's LITERALLY all the information i have to go by and i have no clue how to break it down